Does $\forall x, \exists x$ also needs to be quantified over some sets in zfc subset axiom?
I'm a bit confused on learning zfc subset axiom,

$ F \circ G = \{\langle x,z \rangle \mid \exists y \ \langle x,y \rangle \in G \ and \ \langle y,z \rangle \in F \ \}$

I understand $x \in \cup\cup{F}$, and $z \in \cup\cup{G}$, so $\langle x,z \rangle$ exist, but for the formula after $\mid$, I know it should be some first order formula, so things like $\forall x \phi(x)$,$\exists x \phi(x)$, but we just write arbitrary formula with quantifiers? Should it be $\forall x \in \text{some set},\phi(x)$ and $\exists x \in \text{some set},\phi(x)$?
Which I mean,things before the bar should be something belongs to some set,
so condition after the bar should also first be quantified over some existing set, then state the predicate?
Updated:so in the example I provided, why don't we write $\exists y \in \text{some set},\phi(y)$?

The thing after the bar should be a first-order formula with one free variable (the variable before the bar), as in ${x \in A \mid P(x)}$. When we write ${\langle x, z \rangle \in A \times B \mid P(x, z)}$, it is shorthand for ${q \in A \times B \mid P(\pi_1(q), \pi_2(q))}$, where $\pi_1 : A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_2 : A \times B \to B$ are the first and second projections.

In plain English, the composition of relations $F \subseteq B \times C$ and $G \subseteq A \times B$ is the subset of $A \times C$ consisting of elements $\langle x, z \rangle$ such that there exists $y \in B$ with $\langle x, y \rangle \in G$ and $\langle y, z \rangle \in F$.

I actually mean the forall/exist after the bar, I think my statement causes confusion. I updated a little bit. For my example, then it becomes should ∃∈some set,()

generally that means $\exists y \phi(y)$ is already good enough, for arbitrary $\phi(y)$, then why don't we need first $\exists y \in \text{some set}$ to first establish $y$ itself is well defined, from some set, then $\phi(y)$ ?

You can write $\exists y\in B. \phi(y)$ instead of $\exists y. \phi(y)$ if you like, but it doesn't really make a difference here: the former is shorthand for $\exists y. y \in B \land \phi(y)$, but in your case $\langle x, y \rangle \in G$ already implies $y \in B$.

Remember that ZF set theory is based on single-sorted first-order logic, which only has unbounded quantifiers (over all sets).

so things before bar needs to be said belongs to some set, but things after bar, the quantifiers ranges over all sets?(But a set contains all sets doesn't exist).  So I have to remember this rule like some magic rule?

The comments all seem tangential to your question, but the second paragraph of Dan Velleman's answer does provide the information you asked for. Just to emphasize it: The answer to the title of your posting is no. Variables quantified after | can range over everything.

You wrote: "I understand $x \in \cup\cup F$ and $z \in \cup\cup G$, so $\langle x, z\rangle$ exists."  You don't need to know $x \in \cup\cup F$ and $z \in \cup\cup G$ to conclude that $\langle x, z\rangle$ exists.  All you need is the pairing axiom, which tells you that for any set $x$, $\{x\}$ is a set, and for any sets $x$ and $z$, $\{x, z\}$ is a set.  Applying this repeatedly, you can conclude that $\{\{x\}, \{x, z\}\}$ is a set, and that's how $\langle x, z\rangle$ is defined.
The subset axiom has a restriction: you can form $\{x \in A \mid \phi(x)\}$, but not necessarily $\{x \mid \phi(x)\}$.  You seem to think that this restriction applies more generally--that any time you refer to a set, you must identify some set that it is an element of.  That is not true.  The restriction is specifically for the variable that comes before the vertical line in set-builder notation.  In particular, there is nothing wrong with writing $\forall x \phi(x)$ or $\exists x \phi(x)$, without restricting $x$ to belong to some set.
